# Why does my chrome browser (that is up to date) not render color-scheme: dark as a fallback?

Tags: css

I am trying to learn how 'color-scheme' works in css, but I don't think I am using it correctly. Basically my css looks like this:

```
:root {
color-scheme: dark light;
}
```

If I use **just one value and not a fallback value both 'light' and 'dark' work**, but if used together it always defaults to a light mode? Why is this?

I want it to choose dark mode, but have a fallback on light mode.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color-scheme

Comment: But the color scheme is set through the OS settings. Why would you change it through code?